# How does one show that $\biggl(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}}-\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\biggr)$ is a linear operator?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-transformations

How does one show that $\dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}-\dfrac{\partial^{2}{u}}{\partial{x^{2}}}$ is a linear operator? At first, I was thinking that there might be some distributive property that I've forgotten from Calculus, i.e. $\biggl(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}}-\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\biggr)u$  should somehow equate to $\dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}-\dfrac{\partial^{2}{u}}{\partial{x^{2}}}$.

Comment: A linear operator...on what, exactly?

Comment: You haven't provided an operator but instead an expression of $x$ and $t$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I edited the title. I wanted to know how $\biggl(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}}-\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\biggr)$ is a linear operator on the function $u(x,t)$.

Comment: You've learned in linear algebra that a linear operator respects additivity and multiplication with a scalar quantity. Let $A=\partial_t-\partial^2_x$, then you have to show $A(u+v)=A(u)+A(v)$ and $A(\lambda u)=\lambda A(u)$ for suitable $u(x,t),v(x,t)$ and $\lambda \in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$D=\partial_t-\partial_x^2$$
i.e.
$$D: u \mapsto \partial_tu-\partial_x^2u$$
And $D$ is linear iff $\forall$ scalar $\alpha$ and vectors $u,v$ we have that
$$D(u+\alpha v)=Du+\alpha Dv$$
So you just need show that
$$\partial_t (u+\alpha v)-\partial_x^2(u+\alpha v)=\partial_t 
u -\partial_x^2 u+\alpha (\partial_t v - \partial_x^2 v)$$
Using the properties of the partial derivatives.